# How to create n-gram features?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I am working on a text classification and have already done vectorization and statistical features, I would like to further improve the model by adding ngram features in it.
How can I do that in Python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using sklearn's [**CountVectorizer**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) or [**TfidfVectorizer**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) might be a good starting point. They have **ngram_range** parameter to add ngrams, it works for both word ngrams and char ngrams, depending on the **analyzer** param. See examples on the [**CountVectorizer**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) page, more examples [in this article](https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/machine-learning/how-to-use-count-vectorization-for-n-gram-analysis).